# PHP debugging to list change of datatype of a single variable

Tags: php

Is there any way to debug a PHP code where it will list how many times a variable has undergone a change in its datatype?

For example :

```
$x = 12.4;
//some code
.
.
$x = 'Sam';
//some code
.
.
$x = 'Hello world';
//some code
.
.
$x = 45;
//some code
.
.
$x = 23;
//some code
.
.
$x = true;
```

And the corresponding output would be -

```
float
string
string
integer
integer
boolean
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add `echo gettype($x)` at the position of every occurrance of `//some code`.

From [PHP.net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettype.php):

> Returns the type of the PHP variable var.
>
> Possible values for the returned string are:
>
> - "boolean" "integer" "double" (for historical reasons "double" is    returned in case of a float, and not simply "float")
> - "string"
> - "array"
> - "object"
> - "resource"
> - "NULL"
> - "unknown type"

But you would need to explicitly add this piece of code. I don't think there is any way to hook into assignment of a normal variable.

One alternative is to set the value through a function, or to use an object to store the variable in. The snippet below uses an object with a magic getter and setter to catch setting each property. But of course this may also require a code change for you, and it's quite a bit slower too, so setting every variable like this won't be efficient.

But for a small debugging session it may be useful:

```
<?php
class Vars {
  private $___values = array();

  public function __get($x) {
    return $this->___values[$x];
  }

  public function __set($x, $v) {
    $this->___values[$x] = $v;
    echo gettype($v);
  }  
}

$vars = new Vars();

$vars->x = 'test'; // Echoes 'string'
$vars->x = 10; // Echoes 'integer'
```

Comment: I thought of this but it would be inconvenient for a code of thousand lines

Comment: I don't think there is any way to hook into the assignment of a variable.

Answer (score 2):

you can try this code

```
<?php
     $array=array(); 
     function get_type_variable($var){
        global $array; //make this array global so we can access outside
        $array[]=gettype($var);
        return($array);
    }
    //and you can use like this code
    $x='testing';
    get_type_variable($x);//string
    $x=100;
    get_type_variable($x);//integer
    $x=3.14;
    get_type_variable($x);//double
    $x=true;
    get_type_variable($x);//boolean
    $x=array(1,1,1,1,1);
    get_type_variable($x);//array
    $x=NULL;
    get_type_variable($x);//NULL
    // output Array ( [0] => string [1] => integer [2] => double 
    //[3] => boolean [4] => array [5] => NULL)
    print_r($array);
?>
```

this way you can call get_type_variable() method for variable, when variable needs to changes it's type.